# Preloading images with javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to preload images with javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    preloadImages(
        ['../../Content/Resources/close_mouse_over.png',
        '../../Content/Resources/close.png']);
});

function preloadImages(sources) {
        var image = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            image[i] = new Image();
            image[i].src = sources[i];
        }
    }

function mouseOverForImage(imgId, imgSrcs) {
        document.getElementById(imgId).src = imgSrcs;
    }
```

In Html:

```
<input type="image" src="../../Content/Resources/close.png" name="Action" value="Save" onmouseover="mouseOverForImage('close', '../../Content/Resources/close_mouse_over.png')" 
               onmouseout = "mouseOverForImage('close', '../../Content/Resources/close.png')" id="close" title = "Close" />
```

But request is still sending to server after mouseover. Is not working only in chrome

Comment: IIRC, preloading images doesn't work if it's too early, i.e. `document.images` is still undefined.

Comment: Try replacing `image[i].src = sources[i];` with `image[i].src = sources[i][0];`.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also you probably want to use a single array: `preloadImages(['../../Content/Resources/close_mouse_over.png', '../../Content/Resources/close.png' ]);`

Comment: I'm using chrome and i changed to single array, but it still does not work :(

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Maybe preloading works, but image caching is disabled. How do you think?

Answer (score 1):

As noted within my comment, you are passing an array of arrays to the preLoadImages method.

As a result, you are passing an array to `image[i].src` which means it won't get loaded.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    preloadImages(
        ['../../Content/Resources/close_mouse_over.png', '../../Content/Resources/close.png']);
});

function preloadImages(sources) {
        var image = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            image[i] = new Image();
            image[i].src = sources[i];
        }
    }

function mouseOverForImage(imgId, imgSrcs) {
        document.getElementById(imgId).src = imgSrcs;
    }
```

or, if you want to keep the array of array's, then use

```
function preloadImages(sources) {
        var image = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            image[i] = new Image();
            image[i].src = sources[i][0];
        }
    }
```

Edit, on further investigation, a possible cause is `preloadImages` destroys the `image` array after preloading the images.

try this instead:

```
function preloadImages(sources) {
    window.preloadedImages = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        window.preloadedImages[i] = new Image();
        window.preloadedImages[i].src = sources[i];
    }
}
```

This stores the preloaded images within the window object, allowing them to preload properly.

Hope that helps?

Comment: I don't understand why ['../../Content/Resources/close_mouse_over.png', '../../Content/Resources/close.png'] is array of arrays, it's simple array

Comment: You are right about array of arrays, but it still does not work

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the page that isn't working correctly? How are you testing to see if it is working or not?

Comment: Also, what may be happening, is that you are creating an array within `preloadImages` which is getting destroyed once you finish preloading the images. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: I'm placing breakpoint in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute event and it fires if request is received